# How to make part of an image an href?

Tags: html, image, area

I have made a website, and would like to make the subscribe button clickable (an href).

So far here is my code for that. My problem is that I don't know how to do the coordinates. Is there a website I can use?

```
<map name="subscribe"
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="http://www.google.com" alt="Test">
</map>
```

Here is my image:

[image: It's an image]

Comment: If you are just looking for an online image map generator check http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map Area coords are: left, top, width, height

http://jsfiddle.net/5sXAb/

```
<img width="600px" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ4BD.png" usemap="#subscribe">

<map name="subscribe">
<area shape="rect" coords="230,55,385,100" href="http://www.google.com" alt="Test">
</map>
```

Ninja edit; there are ways round it, for example using imaging software to find the coords, a javascript code the adds a border, or my preferred option - using transparent divs instead.